# Calculation app

Tags: java, android, calculator

I want to do a special calculation app for Android but if i put no or too high numbers and press on calculate it crashes, i did a lot of googleing but found no answer.
This is my second app.
Any helpful tip would be appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void myBerechnen(View v) {

    EditText Input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Input);

    TextView mal2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mal2);
    TextView mal3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mal3);
    TextView mal4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mal4);
    TextView mal5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mal5);
    TextView mal6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mal6);
    TextView mal7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mal7);
    TextView mal8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mal8);
    TextView mal9=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mal9);

    TextView durch2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.durch2);
    TextView durch3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.durch3);
    TextView durch4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.durch4);
    TextView durch5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.durch5);
    TextView durch6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.durch6);
    TextView durch7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.durch7);
    TextView durch8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.durch8);
    TextView durch9=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.durch9);

    Integer Zahl=Integer.parseInt(Input.getText().toString());

    mal2.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2));
    mal3.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3));
    mal4.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4));
    mal5.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5));
    mal6.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6));
    mal7.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7));
    mal8.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8));
    mal9.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9));

    durch2.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 2));
    durch3.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 2 / 3));
    durch4.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 2 / 3 / 4));
    durch5.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5));
    durch6.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6));
    durch7.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6 / 7));
    durch8.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 / 8));
    durch9.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 / 8 / 9));




}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can't represent the results with Integer type, try to use double instead

Comment: you are putting no number is it crashing?

Comment: @kamiha has a point, also please paste the crash stack trace. I'm sure there's an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

```
mal9.setText(String.valueOf(Zahl * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9));
```

Before you are attempting to convert this to string you are multiplying multiple integers with your variable which could possibly be larger than an integer can store. I recommend reading up on [Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and try casting that to a long or double.

Also is there no specific error code when you try to debug it? That would tell you exactly why it crashed.